# Создание прайс-листа в Ruby on Rails

Tags: база-данных, ruby-on-rails, архитектура

Стоит задача создания списка позиций в прайс-листе (с выводом всего прайс-листа на одной из страниц сайта). В одной из колонок (наименование, единица измерения, цена) общей таблицы должен быть выбор одного из значений (при создании записи). Сами позиции должны быть разделены на несколько групп, и должна иметься возможность добавлять новые группы.

Как лучше всего создать такой прайс-лист на *Ruby on Rails*?

Comment: Это тестовое задание куда-то?

Comment: Нет. Просто я плохо знаком с базами данных, да и с RoR не профессионал скажем так.

Comment: Мне если честно видится одна таблица вида: наименование, единицы измерения по порядку (несколько колонок), цена, группа товара. И вывод всего этого в view по группам товара. Пишу для себя. В процессе обучаюсь. Задаю вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень нечетко сформулирована задача. Из того, что понятно, должно быть так:

```
# это класс для товаров
#
# name:string
# price:float
# category_id:integer
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end 

# а это класс для категорий
# 
# name:string
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, dependent: destroy
end 

# класс для единиц измерения
# 
# name:string
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items_units, dependent: destroy
  has_many :units, through: items_units
end 

# класс, который связывает товары с единицами изерения
# 
# item_id:integer
# unit_id:integer
class ItemsUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :items 
  belongs_to :units 
end
```

Вывод делается перебором категорий, в котором перебираются товары в каждой категории:

```
- Category.all.each do |category|
  = category.name
  - category.items.each do |item|
    = item.name
    = item.price
    units:
    - item.units.each do |unit|
      = unit.name
```

В принципе, этого достаточно для старта в правильном направлении.